# tornado parse_config_file not working

Tags: python, tornado

I have a config file **db.py**. It looks as:

```
user="user"
password="pass"
charset="utf8"
collation="utf8_bin"
host="localhost"
db="dbname"
```

I'm trying the following code:

```
from tornado.options import options, parse_config_file
parse_config_file('db.py')

print options.charset
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 5, in <module>
    print options.charset
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/options.py", line 97, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("Unrecognized option %r" % name)
AttributeError: Unrecognized option 'charset'
```

Can someone tell me if I'm doing something wrong? Thanks.

As answered by @JohnZwinck, I used the following:

```
from tornado.options import define, options, parse_config_file
define("charset", type=str)
parse_config_file('db.py')
print options.charset
```

and it works.

Answer (score 4):

You need to "[define](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#tornado.options.define)" your options before parsing and using them.

Comment: I hope you meant something like what I've edited now? So i'll need to define every single option there? I'm hoping for NO as an answer :-P. BTW the example 4 at the [**LINK HERE**](http://technobeans.wordpress.com/2012/08/28/tornado-options/) doesn't do it for every option. Is it a bit incomplete? TIA

Comment: @user3432110: try it and see.  Does it work if you define all the options?  That link you posted seems to define all the options used.

Comment: The edit i've added, it works. Though I have many a options and hence i was wondering if i'll hv to explicitly define the options that i need to use in a particular module. Besides, in order to specify groups and defaults of the params in the config file, i suppose i'll have to use the define. Please correct if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: I think you've got it right, you need to define your options.  If you don't like this, maybe use a different library, e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html